# Mongoose: subdocument CastError: Cast to Array failed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database-schema

I have two schemas:
Schema one (the parent):

```
var slide = require('../model/slide');

var slidesetSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    dataID: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    slides: [slide]
});
```

and the child schema:

```
var slideSchema = new Schema();
// use this method for a recursive definiton
// src https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongoose-orm/0yUVXNyprx8
slideSchema.add({
    no: Number,
    depth: Number,
    audio: [{
        name: String,
        dataID: Schema.Types.ObjectId
    }],
    //subslides: [slideSchema] <- this will be the next step if the other problem is solved
    // it will be used to create a tree like structure
});
```

I have the following situation: the user uploads a pdf file and then my nodejs server creates a new entry (slideset) for the file and for each page it should create a slide and store it into the slideset. Finally the whole thing should be saved into the db:

```
var set = new slideset();
var slides = [];

for (var i = 1; i <= pagecount; i++) {
    var s = new slide({no: i, depth: 1, audio: []});
    slides.push(s);
    // set.slides.push(s); <-- throws "can't call push of undefined",
    // well here http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html they just do the same thing.. why doesn't it work for me?!
}
set.slides = slides;
// some other stuff, like writestream to save the file into db, set set.name and dataID
writestream.on('close', function (file) {
     // save schema
     set.save(function (err) {
         console.err(err);
     }
});
```

the function 'save' throws the following error:

```
ValidationError: CastError: Cast to Array failed for value "{...},{...},..." at path "slides"
```

I tried different possible solutions I've found here on stackoverflow but none of them worked. I hope you can help me :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
var Audio = new Schema({
       name: String,
       dataID: Schema.Types.ObjectId    
});
```

and then

```
slideSchema.add({
    no: Number,
    depth: Number,
    audio: [Audio]
});
```

?